# Unity: Set position of GameObjects as mesh vertices

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, mesh, vertices

for an augmented reality project I want to project an scalable picture ontop of 4 tracked images which should be like a map. Therefore I want to grab the locations of the Images and put an empty on them. The positions from this 4 emptys are then taken into a method to instantiate a plane on runtime. With fixed vertices my code worked well. My problem is that I cant write the positions of the emptys in the mesh vertices Array.

The Array Points contains the GameObjects and the positions of these Objects are passed correctly

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you explain the last bit? "PS: the fixed values for the vertices where stored like this" - seems contradictory to the other code. Also, the game objects you're getting positions from - how and when are the created?

Comment: the Objects are right now to solve this problem just pre made emptys in the room. Want to instantiate them later on runtime when an image Trackable is detected. I started generating a plane on runtime from code with fixed vertices which were handed over manually. To this time my code worked. As I wanted to take the locations of GameObjects it stoped XD

hope it makes sense what I am saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could, however I managed to do it, solve the problem. Not the prettiest code, but it works :)

```
Mesh m = new Mesh();
        m.vertices = new Vector3[]
        {
            new Vector3(Points[0].transform.position.x, Points[0].transform.position.y, Points[0].transform.position.z),
            new Vector3(Points[1].transform.position.x, Points[1].transform.position.y, Points[1].transform.position.z),
            new Vector3(Points[2].transform.position.x, Points[2].transform.position.y, Points[2].transform.position.z),
            new Vector3(Points[3].transform.position.x, Points[3].transform.position.y, Points[3].transform.position.z),
        };
```